# jquery mobile a link can not work while using knockoutjs data-bind

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I write a link by jquery mobile like:
    < a href="#detail" />

it work first time.

then I modify it use ko bind,like:
    < a href="#detail" data-bind="click:newAdvice">

it can not chagePage, I do not know why?who can help me?

Comment: `<a href="#details" data-role="button" data-bind="click:newAdvice">Details</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set for link data-bind click:

```
<a data-bind="click: showHomepage" data-role="button">Homepage</a>
```

This is javascript:

```
self.showHomepage= function () {
        $.mobile.changePage("#Homepage", {
            transition: "slide"
        });
        return false;
    };
```

and html for Homepage is:

```
<div data-role="page" id="Dashboard">
...
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot,It's useful. but what I really want is what make it do not work, would U find it?